# Setting SelectedValue of ASP.NET menu programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, multiview

I have a MultiView and a Menu in my ASP.NET page - each menu item has a Value property which corresponds to the ViewIndex of the tab to show.

I will sometimes need to set the active view programatically, which works fine for the MultiView, but setting the Selected property of the Menu control is a bit more difficult. I could loop through each item til the value matches the view index I want to show, but this seems a bit hacky.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the MultiView's [OnActiveViewChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview.activeviewchanged.aspx) event to select the menu item.

```
protected void myMultiView_ActiveViewChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = ((MultiView)sender).ActiveViewIndex;
    myMenu.FindItem(index.ToString()).Selected = true;
}
```

This way, whenever the view is changed (via SetActiveView(), or otherwise), the menu selection will remain synced. Note that you may also need to set the active view on the `OnMenuItemClick` event of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

**The below code worked for me**

```
if (transViewFlag == 0)
                        {
                            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
                            MenuTransactions.FindItem("0").Selected = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
                           MenuTransactions.FindItem("1").Selected = true;
                        }
```